# ASP.net showmodel dialog dropdown issue in chome (39.xxxx)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome, iis

I have developed asp.net application. In that application opening one page using window.showModalDialog using following script.

var answer = window.showModalDialog(url, "Info", "dialogHeight:680px; dialogLeft:90px; dialogWidth:990px;center:yes;dialogTop:50px;status:no; scroll:yes;");

In popup page contains dropdown list and few text box controls. Once I click the dropdown list all text box will goes read-only also drop down list items not hiding (page was freeze).

when I right click that page (any place) text boxes readonly removed.

This exception was occur only in chrome browser(39.0.2171.65 latest), also I have changed chrome policy for working showmodeldialog.

Comment: We're having the same problem here. It seems that on Chrome 39 the JS engine stops when calling showModalDialog.

Comment: I think this must be a bug on Chrome 39, so I just reported it to Google: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=436827